# Aggregating time series data keeping date column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, aggregate

I have a dataset as below:

```
date          jobcategory
2016-01-01     SP    
2016-01-01     DP   
2016-01-01     SP   
2016-01-01     CP   
2016-01-01     DP   
2016-01-01     DP   
2016-01-01     DP   
2016-01-02     SP   
2016-01-02     CP   
2016-01-02     SP   
2016-01-02     CP   
2016-01-02     DP   
2016-01-02     TP   
2016-01-02     DP   
2016-01-02     DP   
2016-01-02     DP   
2016-01-03     SP   
2016-01-03     SP   
2016-01-03     DP   
2016-01-03     DP   
2016-01-03     SP   
2016-01-03     DP   
2016-01-04     CP   
2016-01-04     MP
```

I am trying to aggregate this to mainting the date field unique while getting a count of one of the job categories in the second column as below:

```
date      jobcategory   Count
2016-01-01     SP       2
2016-01-02     SP       2
2016-01-03     SP       3
2016-01-04     SP       0
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I recommend asking a new question. I'll set the tag python, so this should help pandas users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `df.groupby` on `date` and then `df.merge` with the original date column to get 0 counts as well.

```
In [921]: df[df.jobcategory == 'SP'].groupby('date', as_index=False).count().merge(df[['date']].drop_duplicates(), how='outer').fillna(0)
Out[921]: 
        date  jobcategory
0 2016-01-01          2.0
1 2016-01-02          2.0
2 2016-01-03          3.0
3 2016-01-04          0.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response.  Unfortunately, I am a new and not able to execute this code correctly. Am I supposed to substitute anything for \.?

Comment: @Sree No, you must not. It is just a line continuation character for readability. Look at my answer now.

Comment: @coldspeed  Thanks again.  I get the following error: "Error: unexpected symbol in "abends.jcat[abends.jcat$jobcat == "SP"].groupby" !

Comment: @Sree I'm sorry but I have no idea what you are trying to do. How can you expect me to debug your program?

Comment: The solution I've provided here will work for the data as you have shown. Any other issues are on your end and have nothing to do with me because that's how you framed your question. It's up to you to either fix it yourself or open a new question.

Comment: @coldspeed, my sincere apologies.  I have been looking for a solution in 'R'.  Looks like my comment that "I am a newbie in R" did not come up in full.  My bad!!

Comment: @Sree Wahahaha. You didn't add the tag.